# How do I query a SQL database for a lot of results that don't have any common criteria?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a MS SQL DB with about 2,600 records (each one information on a computer.)  I need to write a SELECT statement that selects about 400 of those records.

What's the best way to do that when they don't have any common criteria? They're all just different random numbers so I can't use wildcards or anything like that.  Will I just have to manually include all 400 numbers in the query?

Comment: Can you provide an sample data or a sample schema?

Comment: Also what is your goal? An elegant solution, the fastest solution, the easiest? The one that works best in general?

Comment: It is not clear at all what will be the criteria selection. Any 400 records will work? If so, use LIMIT. Otherwise, tell us what is the selection criteria. A lit of numbers, as Brian R. Bondy guessed?

Comment: LIMIT does not exist in SQLServer

Comment: Are you looking for the query to return 400 random records? You need to be more specific...

Comment: Why those 400? Do they lack something the other 2200 have?

Comment: So in future, I must remember to never say the word "random" on SO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you have found a deficiency in the database design.  That is, there is something common amongst the 400 records you want and what you need is another column in the database to indicate this commonality.  You could then select against this new column.

Comment: while this may be true. It's not an answer to the question. Otherwise +1

Comment: Maybe, but I think the precision of my answer was inline with the precision of the question ;-)

Answer (score 7):

**If you need 400 specific rows where their column match a certain number:**

Yes include all 400 numbers using an IN clause.  It's been my experience (via code profiling) that using an IN clause is faster than using where column = A or column = B or ...

400 is really not a lot.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column in (12, 13, 93, 4, ... )
```

**If you need 400 random rows:**

```
SELECT TOP 400 * FROM table
ORDER BY NEWID()
```

Comment: I think he knows what one he wants to select (not just a random sampling). He is just saying they are "random" because there is no real rhyme or reason as to why they are selected while others are not.

Comment: I included both ways because I'm not sure which of the 2 the poster meant.

Comment: I do not have proof, but from profiling both alternatives in my app I found that it is faster.  Profile your own code to be sure, but I'm just talking from my own experiences here.

Comment: Then maybe making a declarative statement is a bad thing if you have no proof. Maybe you should say, "It's been my experience that..."

Comment: @Mark Brady: Thanks for the suggestion, I modified my post to be more clear on where my answer came from.

Answer (score 4):

Rather than executing multiple queries or selecting the entire rowset and filtering it yourself, create either a temporary table or or a permanent table where you an insert temporary rows for each ID. In your main query just `join` on your temporary table.

For example, if your source table is...

```
person:
    person_id
    name
```

And you have 400 different `person_id`'s you want, let's say we have a permanent table for our temporary rows, like this...

```
person_query:
   query_id
   person_id
```

You'd insert your rows into `person_query`, then execute your query like this..

```
select
    *

from person p

join person_query pq on pq.person_id = p.person_id

where pq.query_id = @query_id
```

Comment: This still means I have to manually insert those 400 rows one-by-one though, right? But I guess that's unavoidable.

Comment: Yes, you do, but depending on the complexity of the query it's likely going to be faster than any other method. Any way to get 400 items into an 'in' clause would have to involve dynamically constructed SQL, which is another danger.

Answer (score 1):

As Brian Bondy said above, using the IN statement is probably the best way

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column in (12, 13, 93, 4, ... )
```

One good trick is to paste the IDs in from a spreadsheet, if you have one ...

If the IDs of the rows you want are in a spreadsheet, then you can add an extra column to the spreadsheet that CONCATENATES() a comma on to the end of the ID, so that the column in your spreadsheet looks like this:

```
12,
13,
93,
4,
```

then copy and paste this column of data into your query, so it looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column in (
12, 
13, 
93, 
4, 
... 
)
```

It doesn't look pretty but its a quick way of getting all the numbers in.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an XML list or something of the sort which would keep track of what you need to query, and then you could write a query that would iterate through that list bringing all of them back.

[Here](http://vyaskn.tripod.com/passing_arrays_to_stored_procedures.htm) is a website that has numerous examples of performing what you are looking for in a number of different methods (#4 is the XML method).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a table with those 400+ random tokens, and select on those. e.g.,

```
SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE inventory_id IN (SELECT id FROM inventory_ids WHERE tag = 'foo')
```

You still have to maintain the other table, but at least you're not having one ginormous query.

Comment: And yes, you can write that statement as a JOIN, but personally I find this way easier to read.

Comment: Easier to read and much slower if the optimizer can't rewrite it.

Answer (score 0):

I would built a separate table with your selection criteria and then join the tables together or something like that, assuming your criteria is static of course.

Answer (score 0):

Just select the TOP n rows, and order by something random.

Below is a hypothetical example to return 10 random employee names:

```
   SELECT TOP 10
     EMP.FIRST_NAME
    ,EMP.LAST_NAME
   FROM  
     Schema.dbo.Employees EMP
   ORDER BY
     NEWID()
```

Answer (score -1):

For this specific situation (not necessarily a general solution) the fastest and simplest thing is probably to read the entire SQL table into memory and find your matches in your program's code rather than have the database parse a gigantic where clause.